# Is Gdiplus thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, gdi+, thread-safety

I've perused the MSDN documentation and I couldn't find a statement one way or the other.  What I'm interested in is:

1. Can I call GdiplusStartup() on one thread and then use Gdiplus on another thread?  Or do I need to call GdiplusStartup() for each thread?
2. If I have a Bitmap object on thread 1 and different one on thread 2, can they both call Bitmap::DrawImage() at the same time, or do I need to add locking to ensure serialization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534077(VS.85).aspx) states 'You can call GdiplusStartup on one thread and call GdiplusShutdown on another thread', which would indicate that you only need to call GdiplusStartup() once for your process (and use it from any thread).

I'm not sure about question 2. (I think what you meant was can you call Graphics::DrawImage( bitmap ) at the same time?)  You would create a different Graphics class in each thread, right? So there should be no problem.

Comment: I have confirmed this is the case.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer of question 2, according to [MSDN - Security Considerations: GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533801%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> **Thread Synchronization**
>
> It is possible for more than one
>   thread to have access to a single GDI+
>   object. However, GDI+ does not provide
>   any automatic synchronization
>   mechanism. So if two threads in your
>   application have a pointer to the same
>   GDI+ object, it is your responsibility
>   to synchronize access to that object.
>
> Some GDI+ methods return `ObjectBusy` if
>   a thread attempts to call a method
>   while another thread is executing a
>   method on the same object. Do not try
>   to synchronize access to an object
>   based on the `ObjectBusy` return value.
>   Instead, each time you access a member
>   or call a method of the object, place
>   the call inside a critical section, or
>   use some other standard
>   synchronization technique.